# Trouble passing Vector Array through JS classes

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I am experiencing trouble passing and array of Vectors (subNodes) held in a class "Node". To class Main. Any blatant mistakes?

```
// Node class
// other class code
var subNodePos =[]; // array has been correctly populated in node class
// init array in construct
// array has been correctly populated in node class
Node.prototype.getSubNodeArray = function () { return this.subNodePos; }


// Main class
function draw() 
{
// code ...
// can access all object variables and methods except for this one array
var famPos = node.getSubNodeArray(); // passing array // fails here 'undefined'
var temp = famPos[0]; // error
}
```

Comment: Is `node.subNodePos` an actual property?

Comment: What is `node`? How are we supposed to help you with an incomplete example? Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `subNodePos` as a private variable of your `node` constructor.

But this variable is not available to this method:

```
Node.prototype.getSubNodeArray = function () { return this.subNodePos; }
```

You can fix it in at least 2 ways:

**Solution 1. Make `subNodePos` a public member**

Make it a property of `this` in your constructor:

```
function Node() {
    ...
    this.subNodePos = [];
    ...
}

Node.prototype.getSubNodeArray = function () { return this.subNodePos; }
```

**Solution 2. Define `getSubNodeArray` at object level**

This is when you want to keep `subNodePos` private. Then you can keep the `var` declaration, but must reference it without `this`:

```
function Node() {
    ...
    var subNodePos = [];
    ...
    this.getSubNodeArray = function () { return subNodePos; }
    ...
}
```